# Apple Health Kit Data via Rest API

Tags: ios, python-3.x, api

Are there any third party which provide data of apple health kit data using there end points like google fit provide us via rest api's https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started

Comment: No, the user's health data remains on their device for privacy reasons.

Comment: It is accessible using exporting Healtkit data and after that we can get there data right? does any application provide us same thing like i hit there api with username or something like that that there application will be responsible sending that data @Paulw11

Comment: You could write an app that runs on the user's device and asks for HealthKit access or you could write a website that prompts the user to export their health data and upload it but there is no service that automagically has access to the user's HealthKit data

Comment: That what i want does any third party provide us that kind of service using there app or website?

Comment: I would hope not. I certainly wouldn't grant some app access to my health data if they were going to share it with unknown third parties via their web site.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are not.

And there most likely won't be in the future either. This is an easy conclusion to make given how Health Kit integration works today and how Apple has privacy protocols around Health Data -

Integrating Health Kit in your app allows you to see Health Data only after the user has granted relevant permissions (of course). But the user has to explicitly grant permission for *each datatype* (HKObjectType) eg sleepAnalysis, blood glucose etc.

Your app with Health Kit integration can only request Health Data while the app is active in the background and the phone is not locked or running in the foreground. So lets say you have background tasks (BGAppRefreshTask or BGProcessingTask) to request Health Data - this won't work if your phone is locked.

Given these behaviours and other restrictions Apple places around the use of HealthKit, I don't see how there is ever (or at least in the near future) going to be a an api to relay this data.

If you absolutely had to it, your best bet would be to write an application on the device that integrates with HealthKit and exports HealthData to your servers. Then *explicitly* prompt the user to export HealthData from the app every time, and expose an api from your server. Not happening.